# Changing font type and size in GetLegendGraphic

Tags: qgis, getlegendgraphic

I've just exported a map but i've realised the font type of what's exactly is being displayed in the legend isn't the same.

[image]

This is the GetLegendGraphic url referenced in the information tab.

https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/UKSO/UKSO_BGS_Surface/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic&version=1.3.0&format=image/png&layer=OS.Terrain.50

I'm not sure if i have to set the metadataurl to something to allow me to modify the legend. I've tried adding "legend_options=fontName=Arial" to the end of it but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

A WMS service is merely required to return an image when asked for a legend graphic. It doesn't have to provide you with a way to change that image (it might be a static image on the server). Some services go above and beyond the standard and allow you to specify a [`LEGEND_OPTIONS`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#controlling-legend-appearance-with-legend-options) parameter. But it appears that the one you are talking to is not one of those (if only BGS had saved money and effort by going for an open source server).